# Unable To Install Simple JWT in my Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

Here's my setup right now:

Pip Freeze:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.0
djangorestframework==3.10.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.6.0
PyJWT==2.0.1
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

Settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig',
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```

When I run $ python manage.py runserver I get this error

```
ImportError: Could not import 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_simplejwt'.
```

I have tried importing it at the top of settings.py like this

```
import rest_framework_simplejwt
```

and have tried adding it to my installed_apps.

Nothing is working.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I'm following this guide:
https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: try putting `import sys;print(sys.executable)` at the top of your settings ... my guess is that you pip installed it to a different version of python than the one running it... you might be able to run `python -m pip install ...` to make sure it targets the same python that you are running (maybe)

Comment: Thank you!  I ran the command python pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt and I am no longer getting the error.  I will have to verify that it's working but I've stopped getting the same error at least!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that you are using the right env.
may there is a difference between the environment that you run 'pip freeze' and the python environment that Django is using.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error myself, whenever you run into a problem where you're unable to call a package it's mainly due to the fact that it is not installed, try...

`pip3 install djangorestframework-simplejwt`

credit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9st-DgQoWc

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart your machine and install

- pip install djangorestframework-jwt
- pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
  please ensure those lib's install or not

Click [here](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)!Check this link for the installation as well